# Show that $[E:F] \le n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a separable irreducible polynomial of degree n with coefficients in a field F. Let E be a splitting field of f(x) over F. Show that $[E:F] \le n!$

Answer (score 0):

Since the polynomial is separable, it has n distinct roots in  the splitting field. Let $K=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ be the splitting field. Then $[F(\alpha_1):F]=n$ because $f$ is an irreducible polynomial. Now use induction on the number of roots.

Comment: So I used that to show that $[E:F] = n!$, how do I show that $[E:F]$ can be less than $n!$? Since the degrees multiply, I multiplied $n*(n-1)\cdots*2*1 = n!$ Is it true that $[E:F] \le [F(\alpha_1):F]*[F(\alpha_2):F]\cdots*[F(\alpha_n):F]$? Or does $[E:F]$ actually equal this product?

Comment: No, equality does not hold always.